# About CPU operation and I/O processing

Tags: operating-system

My question is why do we want to have CPU's operation overlap with that of the I/O processing. I have been thinking about optimization and such but yet to arrive at a conclusion.

If anyone is able to answer this question, it will be great. :D

Comment: What do you mean with "CPU's operation overlap with that of that of the I/O processing"? Can you please clarify, and perhaps give some example?

Comment: An IO operation, from the CPU pov,  is something like "write this here. now keep reading from there until a bit flips" or "write this here. now do something else until an interrupt is raised". As you can see there is plenty of room for doing useful stuff instead of reading continuosly of waiting for an interrupt doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I/O is generally very slow compared to the operating frequency of the CPU.

Suppose you have a 1GHz CPU that's capable of executing one instruction every clock cycle. That means the CPU is able to execute one instruction every nanosecond.

Now let's assume you want to fetch some data from your hard drive. Disk operations often take place in the milisecond scale, and we'll assume your drives are fast enough to fetch the data in only 1ms.

If the CPU just sit around and wait for the disk to fetch the data, the CPU will waste 1 million nanoseconds doing nothing, whereas it could be executing 1 million instructions for another task. When a program has a lot of IO access, those wasted cycles stacks up and become noticeable if you let the CPU wait and do nothing. This is why it's a good idea to overlap computation with IO so CPU cycles aren't wasted.

This is also why your computer becomes super unresponsive when your main memory is full, and the CPU has to page frequently to the disk. Your CPU cannot perform any useful task unless the data it needs has been retrieved from the disk into the main memory, so it must sit around and wait for the IOs to complete.